# Google Sheets API call creates scientific numbers that I cannot then run calculations on

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am using API in Google Sheets to call prices of cryptocurrencies vrs Bitcoin
from URL: https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers?quotes=BTC

In some cases I am getting scientific notation instead of the x.xxxxxxxx number value. (e.g. Verge coin price (in bitcoin) is currently pulling in *9.4e-7* instead of *0.00000094*)

I cannot then do any formula work on the imported data because it is not converting back to the number, and I have so far found no way to convert it or stop it being imported as a scientific number.

I have tried formatting the import cells to text, but that still pulls the scientific number in from the API call (I have contacted coinpaprika support to see if they know a way around it).

What I need is a way to convert that scientific number into x.xxxxxxxx number format so that I can then use it in a formula to calculate the value (in bitcoin) of my holdings in a particular cryptocurrency.

Comment: Since question this involves the use of an external API and not Google Apps Script regular or advanced services I think that this question belongs to [so] as is very likely that the solution will be the use a JavaScript method or something specific to that API rather than something specific from Google Sheets/ Google Apps Script unless you want to use a Google Sheets function to be used on a formula.

Comment: but Google Sheets should have the ability to convert text to a number, no? if you can give me that then this will be solved that way, so it is still relevant to Google Sheets in this context.

 How to convert the text of a cell with 8.8e-7 to the number 0.00000088 so it can be used in calculations?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, and the solution.

ImportJSON is calling the API using the function `ImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions)` from a script. It seems this was automatically truncating the pulled data. So I added the parseOption to stop it truncating the numbers, and it needed the NoInherit option as well in order to work on my sheet.

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers?quotes=BTC",,"noInherit,noTruncate")
```

Changing that in the script now pulls bitcoin price in the format x.xxxxxxxx instead of scientific notation, and I can now use it for calcuations in the Google Sheet.

Answer (score -1):

You need either to set the column width to such value that imported value does not need to be auto-shrunk by Google Sheets, or you can use one of round formulas (**`ROUND`**, **`ROUNDUP`**, **`ROUNDDOWN`**) to trim off decimal places.

In some cases, you could force the imported value to be imported as a text string and then just multiply it by 1 like:

```
=TO_TEXT(IMPORT...("...", "..."))*1
```

or like:

```
=VALUE(TO_TEXT(IMPORT...("...", "...")))
```

Comment: Setting the cell width made no difference.  ROUNDDUP function gives the correct solution when I mouse over the formula in the cell I see 0.0000088 in blue, but then it gives the error - _"Function ROUNDDOWN parameter 1 expects number values. But '8.8e-7' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."_   TO_TEXT just seems to copy the scientific notation, so I still get '8.8e-7' in the new cell.  VALUE - All variations just keep ending with the error: _"VALUE parameter '8.8e-7' cannot be parsed to number."_

Comment: apologies for the error in the above comment, I meant "ROUNDDOWN"